# How to keep showing Administration menu when changing user?

Tags: 7, users, toolbar

I'm using the Administration menu, like thousands of others. I recently discovered that one can change from user by hoovering over the red "hello user" button at the right. It's a nice feature, but I was wondering if it's possible to keep showing the toolbar when one changes from user (even when that user doesn't have permission to use it) in order to be able to switch back to administrator quickly. When I, as an administrator, would like to see how the page looks like for another user, I now always have to log in again as administrator - quite time consuming.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Masquerade module for seeing how a page looks like for another user https://drupal.org/project/masquerade.

Another way is to duplicate your tab in incoqnito tab or in another browser and become another user there.

Third way is to make sure (if possible) your browser remembers user names and passwords on login forms. Then logging in as administrator is as easy as typing the first letter to the username field and pressing enter. This is less cool of course...